# How to change state immediately and then change back to empty after a delay using UseState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function where I'd like to set the `successMessage` to "success" and then after 5 seconds I'd like to set `successMessage` to an empty string again, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Preferably I'd like to create a helper function where I can pass in 3 variables - function to run before (`setSuccessMessage('Success!')`), function to run after (`setSuccessMessage('')`) and the delay (5000ms)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need useEffect as well as useState.

Answer (score 0):

The Simpliest solution that runs timeout whenever the message changes to anything but empty string. Bear in mind that this example is written by hand without any testing ;)

```
const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');
const timerRef = useRef(null);

const resetMessage = () => {
  clearTimeout(timerRef.current)
  timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => setSuccessMessage(''), 5000)
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (successMessage !== '') resetMessage();
}, [successMessage, resetMessage]);
```